# Embedding R in C#

Tags: c#, r

I am trying to connect R to C# (vs 2008) on Win 7 64 bit by referencing to

```
STATCONNECTORCLNTLib;
StatConnectorCommonLib;
STATCONNECTORSRVLib;.
```

But no matter what I do I still get `"Exception from HRESULT: 0×80040013"` at the code line with Init(“R”).
I tried RAndFriends, 3 different versions, then I tried to install separately R and COM Server, rscproxy…nothing works.

A simple piece of code like this fails:

```
  StatConnector rconn = new STATCONNECTORSRVLib.StatConnector();
    rconn.Init("R");
```

Updates: When installing R version 2.13, the issue is back..
         When installing RandFriends, latest version, on win 7, c# 2010, still not working.

Has anyone managed to connect R and C# in Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

The COM library is 64bit? If its not you should configure the project to build only as a 32bit application.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. The COM library was 32 bit.

Comment: And now the problem is back...I installed a new version of R -2.13.0 and nothing is working, again...I installed the COM server (version 3.0), in Windows 7 compatible mode. I checked the versions of R stored in registry...I have no clue what I should do in order to make it work..

Answer (score 1):

So, for Windows 7 Users who have got this error message when trying to connect R and C#,I am offering you my solution:

- Uninstall all versions of R and COM server (also remove manually all the folders from Program Files and Program Files (x86))
- If possible , install Visual C# 2010 (worked for me- I was using vs 2008 pro edition)
- Download RandFriends, and run it in Windows 7 Compatible mode
- Make sure rscproxy is installed(type  in R console library ("rscproxy"))
- Remove the old references from your project, and add them again

Now it should work! :-)